# How to format external links at build time?

Tags: javascript, gulp, hugo

I have a Hugo site with some JavaScript and Gulp.
I would like to automatically detect and format `<a>` links so that an "external link" icon and "target=_blank" are added.

For now I do it in the client browser with some JavaScript:

```js
// EXTERNAL LINKS
$(document.links).filter(function() {
  return this.hostname != window.location.hostname
      && this.hostname != "domain-name-base-url.com"
      && this.hostname != "another-domain-name-base-url-to-be-treated-as-internal.com"
}).attr('target', '_blank').addClass("external");
```

But I would like to do it at build time for performance reasons.

How can I move this to a post-build gulp task? I tried some stuff with `.pipe(replace...)` but couldn't manage to do it. Can I even do it at Hugo build time?

If anyone knows even a simpler way to achieve this (allow the user to type in Markdown forgetting about whether a link is external or no, and adding `target=_blank" and an icon at build time)... any magical library or best practice?

Comment: What "performance reasons" are you facing, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Rather spend time trying to develop a solution, you could simply replace any external links manually.

With **Markdown 2.5.2** you can use the following syntax

```
[link](url){:target="_blank"}
```

If that doesn't work, just use regular HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Hello, world!</a>
```

More information about internal and external links in Hugo can be found [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/hugo/how-to-create-link-with-target-blanks-in-hugo-markdown/).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** You can also do this in your templates, by using the `replace` function to add that attribute to all anchor elements:

```
{{ $content := replace .Content "<a " "<a target=\"_blank\" " | safeHTML }}
{{ $content }}
```

---

You can configure Blackfriday, Hugo's markdown processor, to open links in a new tab by adding this to the bottom of your `config.toml` file:

```
[blackfriday]
  hrefTargetBlank = true
```

From the [Blackfriday options](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#blackfriday-options) docs:

> `hrefTargetBlank`
>
> default: `false`
>   Blackfriday flag: `HTML_HREF_TARGET_BLANK`
>   Purpose: `true` opens (external links) **absolute** links in a new window or tab. While the `target="_blank"` attribute is typically used for external links, Blackfriday does that for all absolute links ([ref](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/internal-links-in-same-tab-external-links-in-new-tab/11048/8)). One needs to make note of this if they use absolute links throughout, for internal links too (for example, by setting `canonifyURLs` to `true` or via `absURL`).

Answer (score 0):

Hugo has all you need with Markdown render hooks: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/#markdown-render-hooks

Tutorial for Hugo external link:

Create a layouts/_default/_markup/render-link.html

```
{{- $parsedTitle := dict -}}
{{- with .Title -}}
  {{- $parsedTitle = partial "functions/parse-title-attribute.html" . -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- $baseurl := urls.Parse .Page.Site.BaseURL -}}
{{- $desturl := urls.Parse .Destination -}}

<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"
  {{- with $parsedTitle.title }} title="{{ . }}"{{- end -}}
  {{- with $parsedTitle.attributes -}}
    {{- range $k, $v := . -}}
      {{- printf " %s=%q" $k $v | safeHTMLAttr -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- if and (strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http") (not (strings.HasPrefix $desturl.Host $baseurl.Host)) }} target="_blank" rel="external nofollow noopener"{{ end -}}
  >{{ .Text | safeHTML }}</a>

{{- /* Strip trailing space. Code by djibe, thanks to jmooring & killbus */ -}}
```

Now you have 2 possibilities:

- Use in markdown: `[External link](https://discourse.gohugo.io/ "{rel='nofollow'}")` (however all external links will be flagged external nofollow except if you remove line `{{- if and (strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http") (not (strings.HasPrefix $desturl.Host $baseurl.Host)) }} target="_blank" rel="external nofollow noopener"{{ end -}}`)
- or standard `[External link](https://discourse.gohugo.io/)`

NB. Shortcodes are not affected by this so you have to specify the suitable behaviour on every link.